# Move files from the build folder (after build) to a different folder with a relative path - Webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to switch from grunt to webpack. In grunt, we have a task that copies folders from **build** to a different folder using a relative path. This tasks runs after all the files have been built and are in the build folder. We do this for dev purposes.

I cannot seem to find a plugin that will copy folders from build to a different folder. I have seen the copy-webpack-plugin, but it seems it only moves files/folders to the build folder. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://github.com/gregnb/filemanager-webpack-plugin, it has `onEnd` option which allows to do stuff after build

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: With `copy-webpack-plugin` you can actually move files anywhere you want, not only `build` folder, but it doesn't have `onEnd` option, it moves them before the build or in parallel, I guess.

Comment: One of drawback of `filemanager-webpack-plugin` is it don't update webpack assets state. In case if you need to use webpack to serve assets for you application they won't be available. Another drawback in `filemanager-webpack-plugin` it doesn't support move operation with wildcard, since it uses `mv` node module under the hood. May be in your case it shouldn't be a problem.